# Header function average gives me wrong result in C. If I call the "average" function which I have created in my header, the result is not as expected

Tags: c, function

I have created an header file in C and called it statistic.h. I have created a function to calculate the average ( I called the function "average"). But when I use to formula :
sizeof (list)/sizeof (list[0]) , the result is wrong.

header file below:

```
 #ifndef STATISTIC_H_INCLUDED
 #define STATISTIC_H_INCLUDED

float average(int list[]){
int i;
float sum_elements,mean;

int total =sizeof (list)/sizeof (list[0]);
for (i=0;i<total;i++){
    sum_elements=sum_elements+list[i];
                     }
     mean = sum_elements / total;

return mean;


 }

 #endif // STATISTIC_H_INCLUDED


//see main code below where I'm trying to call the function I have previously created in the header.

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "statistic.h"
int main(){

int list[]={26,12,16,56,112,24};

float mean=average(list); // I'm calling the average function I created in my header
printf("%f",mean);

return 0;
/*The average is 41.00 but I'm getting 19.00 instead . If I don't use 
the sizeof function and manually declare the variable total=6 (the 
number of element in the list), it gives me the correct result 
(41.00).*/
```

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof (list)/sizeof (list[0]);` in `average` doesn't work since `list` decays into an `int*` when passed as an argument to the function. You need to send the size of the list into the function as an argument.

Example:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float average(int list[], size_t total) { // send total in as an argument
    float sum_elements = 0;               // note: initialize sum_elements

    for (size_t i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        sum_elements = sum_elements + list[i];
    }

    return sum_elements / total;
}

int main() {
    int list[] = {26, 12, 16, 56, 112, 24};

    // do the size calculation here, where `list` is defined instead:
    float mean = average(list, sizeof list / sizeof *list);
    printf("%f", mean);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nW5MEb1qa)

Comment: Thank you so much Ted. I have been stack on this for days. You made it look so simple and clear. God bless you.

Comment: @FabioGenua Glad to hear it! You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The `list` parameter in your `average` function isn't an array, it's a pointer, so the `sizeof` trick doesn't work.

Unless it's the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and its value will be the address of the first element in the array.

When you *call* `average`:

```
float mean=average(list);
```

the expression `list` is converted from type "6-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`" and the value of the expression is the same as `&list[0]`, so what `average` actually receives is a pointer value, not an array.

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both "adjusted" to `T *a` - all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`, not an array of `T`.

You will have to pass the array size as a separate parameter:

```
float average( int *list, size_t list_size ) 
{
  ...
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < list_size; i++ ) 
    ...
}
```

and call it as

```
mean = average( list, sizeof list / sizeof list[0] );
```

You also need to explicitly initialize `sum_elements` to `0` in the `average` function.

Comment: Thank you so much. "Professors" at Uni couldn't answer my question. I hope one day I will be able to give back all the help I'm getting in here. Thanks again John. Much appreciated.